# catch all errors in express not working

Tags: error-handling, express

I want to server a error.ejs file for all errors that are not handled individually.

This code does not do anything when I get a duplicate key error from mongoose user.save()
http://expressjs.com/guide.html#error-handling

app.js

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
  res.status(500);
  res.render('error', { error: "Woops, we encountered an error..." });
});
```

routes/index.js

```
user.save(function(err){
    if ( err ) throw err;
});
```

The example below gives me this error: Caught exception: [ReferenceError: next is not defined]

```
user.save(function(err){
    if ( err ) next(err);
});
```

Comment: don't throw them. `next(err)`

Comment: do i need a return below the next(err)?

Comment: sure, or you can do an if/else

Comment: next(err) tells me next() doesn't exist.

Comment: because you didn't put `user.save` inside a middleware. of course `next` isn't defined...

Comment: no i put it in my route. anyway to recover from this?

Answer (score 3):

Your snippet

```
user.save(function(err){
    if ( err ) next(err);
});
```

is presumably inside a route that has a function( req, res ) on it?

What you need to do is a "next" on that function

```
function MyRoute( req, res, next ) {
  user.save(function(err){
    if ( err ) 
      return next(err);

    // carry on here doing whatever
  });
}

app.get('/some/route', MyRoute);
```